# AEM 5.6.1 SP2 Adobe Granite SSO Authentication Handler not working

Tags: single-sign-on, aem

Im using Adobe Experience Manager (5.6.1.20130606) and was able to successfully configure the [1] SSO authentication. I have tested using cookie, header and query parameter all working as expected.

[1] https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/single_sign_on.html#Configuring SSO

After installing the [2] SP2 package, suddenly SSO got broken. I have checked my SSO configuration nothing is changed but all of a sudden SSO authentication cannot work anymore.

[2] https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/release_notes_service_pack_2.html

Existing Adobe Granite SSO Authentication Handler config:

Path: /
Service Ranking: 0
Header Names: cq-user
Cookie Names: cq-user
Parameter Names: cq-user
User Map:
Format: AsIs
Trusted Credential Attribute: TrustedInfo

Curl Test:

C:\Users\Homer>curl.exe -D - -H "cq-user:admin" http://localhost:4502/siteadmin
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: Close
Server: Day-Servlet-Engine/4.1.52
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 04:08:47 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Sling (Development)"

Is there anyone here had encountered the same issue? Is there any available fix for this?

Thanks in advance for those who will reply.

Answer (score 0):

we are working on the same environment and have also problems with SSO.
We fixed this with another version of the dispatcher module.
Please try to use the Version 4.15 of the Dispatcher. Maybe this will help you!
Actually I am working with Adobe on a ticket to fix the SSO problems with the newer Versions of the dispatcher module.

regards

Dirk

Comment: I have raised this concern to daycare and the fix they have suggested is to modify the repository.xml to add the TrustedInfo property.